# how to solve this error Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'kishan' in php

Tags: javascript, php

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="STARK-PC";
    $password="YES";
    $dbname="kishan";
    $conn=new mysqli("localhost","STARK-PC","YES","kishan");
```

my database not select so what i can do for select my database ?

Comment: are you sure your password is 'YES' ?

Comment: check the setting's carefully

Comment: Did you create those variables in the first place?

Comment: $username="root" and $password="" try this its default

Comment: You fix this the same way as when you log into facebook and you type in the wrong password.

Comment: Offtopic: Not even Tony Stark would go that way with naming his PC like that :D

Answer (score 2):

May be you are putting your pc name to your mysql username and password
If you are using default mysql settings you can put.

```
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $dbname="kishan";
    $conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of argument, I will not tell you actually that this is bad habit to put your info out like that in your html file. (since it is).

However, first of all, did you create those variables (as is this info in your phpmyadmin?) Asuming it is not, use the following:

```
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="kishan";
$conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
```

Root is the standard username, password is by default blank with this user.

Further, as you see, those variables you put down, you dont use them, which you should. Check the last line. I used those variables, instead of the content of those variables.

Also, just a headsup if you want to include this in your file: start this BEFORE you open the html.

```
<?php
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $dbname="kishan";
    $conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
?>
<html>
<body>
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'STARK-PC','YES') or die('check your user name or password');
mysqli_select_db($conn,'kishan') or die('error in your database');
```

try this and check error message and solve that..... thanks